# Redirecting to external validation page using oauth with drupal_http_request()

Tags: authentication-authorization

I'm working on a module to integrate with the [Piryx API](http://code.google.com/p/piryx-api/), and per the [OAuth documentation](http://dev.piryx.com/docs/oauth.html), I should be redirected to an external page where the user can allow access to my application.  The problem is that I'm using drupal_http_request():

```
$response = drupal_http_request($url, $headers, 'GET', $data);
```

to get the data, and the page markup is returned in $response['data'] instead of redirecting me to the external page (if I put the URL in my browser, it brings up the page fine).  Is there something I can do to redirect to the external URL so the user can allow access, or do I just somehow need to use the markup to display it in my site?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the case the request is redirect to a different URL, `$response->code` is 301, and `$response->redirect_url` is the redirection URL. If the request is redirect, you can call `drupal_http_request()` using `$response->redirect_url` as new URL.

See [aggregator_aggregator_fetch()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--aggregator--aggregator.fetcher.inc/function/aggregator_aggregator_fetch/7) as example of Drupal function that verifies the request is being redirected.

```
  // Process HTTP response code.
  switch ($result->code) {
    case 304:
      break;
    case 301:
      $feed->url = $result->redirect_url;
      // Do not break here.
    case 200:
    case 302:
    case 307:
      if (!isset($result->data)) {
        $result->data = '';
      }
      if (!isset($result->headers)) {
        $result->headers = array();
      }
      $feed->source_string = $result->data;
      $feed->http_headers = $result->headers;
      break;
    default:
      watchdog('aggregator', 'The feed from %site seems to be broken, due to "%error".', array('%site' => $feed->title, '%error' => $result->code . ' ' . $result->error), WATCHDOG_WARNING);
      drupal_set_message(t('The feed from %site seems to be broken, because of error "%error".', array('%site' => $feed->title, '%error' => $result->code . ' ' . $result->error)));
  }
```

If you want to redirect the users to `$result->redirect_url`, and not requesting that URL with `drupal_http_request()`, you use the following code.

```
drupal_goto($response->redirect_url, array('absolute' => TRUE));
```

Comment: OK, I'm confused.  The response code I'm getting is actually 302.  What I can't figure out is how to actually redirect the user to the location in $response->redirect_url, because I need the user the allow access to my application on that page.  Calling drupal_http_requeset() again doesn't do that; it just gives me another response object.

Comment: If you look at `aggregator_aggregator_fetch()`, you will see that the code 302 is handled as if the `drupal_http_request()` returned 200.